# Should you Store Table Count in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have inherited a project and one thing that stuck out is that some of the tables record count need to be displayed as a statistic so the user.

I would have just done `select Count(*) from Table1` and called it a day, but they seem to have it whenever something is inserted into that table another table get updated with the newest count.

So say `Table1 had 100 rows`, this `storageTable` would have a column called `Table1` with a count of 100. If a new row was inserted in `Table1` then the `storageTable` would be updated to 101.

The only thing I can think why this would have been done was because of speed. If I do the `select Count(*) from Table1` it takes like 4 seconds to return the count as there are over 4 million rows in the table.

Since they have many of these stats that have to be displayed the time could add up.

I always learned that calculations should not be stored but calculated on the fly, so I am not sure if this was bad practice to do or since it is a count, it is ok.

I just think it would be hard to make sure it is in sync(which currently it is out of sync by at least a 100).

Comment: You could try your table idea with triggers to update counts.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither a good nor a bad practice.  It is merely cumbersome.

Obviously, having the summary table is very handy and speedy for getting the summary data.  That is convenient.

Keeping the summary data up-to-date, though, requires managing triggers on all the tables -- both for `insert` and `delete`.  That is cumbersome, requiring appropriate logic in each table.  This also has a (small) impact on the performance of these operations.  It also requires care when bulk loading data and using `truncate table`.

Clearly, the designers of the system you are using thought that getting the counts is so important that it is worth the overhead.

Comment: I think it also depends on the way how data enter the table and how the statistics is used. For a table used for OLTP operations it is indeed cumbersome to keep track. For a table that is fed by a single ETL job it is not (and I believe it is indeed a good idea that an ETL process has the ability to keep track on its inserts, deletes and updates).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue when I was working on one big gps project. The gps device used to send the coordinate on every 5 secs and I need to calculate total number of cordinates , accumulated mileage etc . I did it in 2 approaches

1. Made a seperate database  based on redis and calculated all those counts and mileages on the fly and saved it in redis
2. Run a queue using an application to make a scheduled job to save that data from redis to mysql.

It depends on your requirement , if you do not have too much insert queries you can simply make the seperate table on mysql otherwise you can use technologies like redis .